# AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5

Tags: java

Buenas noches tengo un problema y es que en la pantalla para pedir datos y mandarlos a llamar en SQL me aparece este problema.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5
at La_Estancia.Reservaciones.listar(Reservaciones.java:46)
at La_Estancia.Reservaciones.<init>(Reservaciones.java:29)
at La_Estancia.Reservaciones$3.run(Reservaciones.java:277)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Es el unico error que aparece en mi programa, se que es un problema sobre alguna parte del codigo pero no se donde puede estar el error del programa.

Este es mi pantalla para pedir datos y mandarlos a crear en el SQL en donde una vez que dan guarda manda la inforamcion.
El problema que tengo es que ni siquiera inicia el programa una vez que le doy a ejecutar este aparece el error de la parte de arriba

```
    public class Reservaciones extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    Date firstDate, SecondDate;
    String FechaEnt, FechaSal;
    ConexionDB con = new ConexionDB();
    Connection cn;
    Statement stt;
    ResultSet RSe;
    DefaultTableModel DModel;
    int id;
    


public Reservaciones() {
    initComponents();
    listar();
}

public void listar(){
    String sql="SELECT * FROM reservaciones";
    
     try {
        cn=con.getConnection();
        stt = cn.createStatement();
        RSe = stt.executeQuery(sql);
        Object[] reservaciones = new Object[5];
        DModel =  (DefaultTableModel) TablaDatos.getModel();
        while(RSe.next()){
            reservaciones[0]=RSe.getInt("Id_Reservacion");
            reservaciones[2]=RSe.getString("Fecha_Entrada");
            reservaciones[3]=RSe.getString("Fecha_Salida");
            reservaciones[4]=RSe.getInt("Dias");
            reservaciones[5]=RSe.getString("Id_habitacion");
            DModel.addRow(reservaciones);
        }
        TablaDatos.setModel(DModel);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Reservaciones.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}


@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    SelReservacion = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    SelDias = new javax.swing.JTextPane();
    jLabel6 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    IDHabi = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    SelEstatus = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    EntradaF = new com.toedter.calendar.JDateChooser();
    SalidaF = new com.toedter.calendar.JDateChooser();
    jScrollPane2 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    TablaDatos = new javax.swing.JTable();
    jSeparator1 = new javax.swing.JSeparator();
    jLabel7 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Berlin Sans FB Demi", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
    jLabel1.setText("ID Reservacion");

    jLabel2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Berlin Sans FB Demi", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
    jLabel2.setText("Fecha Entrada");

    jLabel3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Berlin Sans FB Demi", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
    jLabel3.setText("Fecha Salida");

    jLabel4.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Berlin Sans FB Demi", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
    jLabel4.setText("Días");

    jLabel5.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Berlin Sans FB Demi", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
    jLabel5.setText("ID Habitación");

    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(SelDias);

    jLabel6.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Berlin Sans FB Demi", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
    jLabel6.setText("Estatus");

    IDHabi.setEditable(false);

    jButton1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Berlin Sans FB Demi", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
    jButton1.setText("Guardar");
    jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    TablaDatos.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
        new Object [][] {

        },
        new String [] {
            "ID Reservacion", "Fecha Entrada", "Fecha Salida", "ID Habitacion", "Estatus"
        }
    ));
    jScrollPane2.setViewportView(TablaDatos);

    jLabel7.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Berlin Sans FB Demi", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
    jLabel7.setText("Lista de referencia de habitaciones");

    jButton2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Berlin Sans FB Demi", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
    jButton2.setText("Calcular Día");
    jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(34, 34, 34)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jLabel5)
                    .addComponent(jLabel4)
                    .addComponent(jLabel6)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                        .addComponent(jLabel3))))
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(IDHabi, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 269, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(SelEstatus, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 136, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jButton1)
                    .addGap(50, 50, 50))
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 146, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                .addComponent(EntradaF, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addComponent(SalidaF, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                            .addGap(31, 31, 31)
                            .addComponent(jButton2))
                        .addComponent(SelReservacion, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 266, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))))
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(jSeparator1)
            .addContainerGap())
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(23, 23, 23)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 637, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jLabel7))
            .addGap(0, 20, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(41, 41, 41)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addComponent(SelReservacion, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(EntradaF, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel2))
                    .addGap(12, 12, 12)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(SalidaF, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel3)))
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(33, 33, 33)
                    .addComponent(jButton2)))
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(jLabel4)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(36, 36, 36)
                    .addComponent(jButton1))
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel5)
                        .addComponent(IDHabi, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel6)
                        .addComponent(SelEstatus, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))))
            .addGap(39, 39, 39)
            .addComponent(jSeparator1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 10, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addComponent(jLabel7)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 219, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap(37, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    agregar();
    
    for (int i = 0; i < TablaDatos.getRowCount(); i++) {
    DModel.removeRow(i);
        i-=1;
    }
    listar();
}                                        

private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
    FechaEnt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(EntradaF.getDate());
    FechaSal = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(SalidaF.getDate());
    firstDate = EntradaF.getDate();
    SecondDate = SalidaF.getDate();
    long diff = SecondDate.getTime() - firstDate.getTime();
    TimeUnit time = TimeUnit.DAYS; 
    long diffrence = time.convert(diff, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    SelDias.setText(""+diffrence);
    SelEstatus.setText("Fuera");
    System.out.println("TFecha : "+FechaEnt);
}                                        


public void agregar(){
    int Id_Reservacion = Integer.parseInt(SelReservacion.getText());
    String Fecha_Entrada = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(EntradaF.getDate());
    String Fecha_Salida = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(SalidaF.getDate());
    int Dias = Integer.parseInt(SelDias.getText());
    String Id_habitacion = IDHabi.getText();
    cn = con.getConnection();
    String sql = "INSERT INTO reservaciones VALUES ('"+Id_Reservacion+"','"+Fecha_Entrada+"','"+Fecha_Salida+"','"+Dias+"',"+null+")";
    System.out.println(sql);
    try {
        stt = cn.createStatement();
        stt.executeUpdate(sql);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Reservaciones.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    Hilo hilo = new Hilo(Dias);
    hilo.HiloRun();
}

public static void main(String args[]) {   
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new Reservaciones().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private com.toedter.calendar.JDateChooser EntradaF;
private javax.swing.JTextField IDHabi;
private com.toedter.calendar.JDateChooser SalidaF;
private javax.swing.JTextPane SelDias;
private javax.swing.JTextField SelEstatus;
private javax.swing.JTextField SelReservacion;
private javax.swing.JTable TablaDatos;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel6;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel7;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane2;
private javax.swing.JSeparator jSeparator1;
// End of variables declaration                   }
```

Esta es mi pantalla para llamar Hilo para mandar a llamar los datos que seran lanzados a la ventana del formulario para ver los datos.

```
package La_Estancia;


  public class Hilo {
   int x;
public Hilo(int x){
    this.x=x;   
}


public void HiloRun() {
 System.out.println("Iniciando ");
    try {
        for (int contar=x; contar>0; contar--){
            Thread.sleep(400);
            System.out.println("Analizando en "+contar);
        }
    }catch (InterruptedException exc){
        System.out.println( "Error se interrumpio el proceso.");
    }
    System.out.println("Se ha realizado con exito ");}}
```

Esta es mi pantalla para mandar a llamar la base de datos

```
public class ConexionDB {
Connection con;
public ConexionDB(){
    try {
         Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/la_estancia", "root", "Angeldark666.");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ConexionDB.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } 
}
public Connection getConnection(){
    return con;
}    }
```

Comment: **Javascript != Java**: es como comparar gatos con gallinas. Pista: mirá una y otra vez el contenido de tu función `listar`: ¿de cuántas posiciones es tu array? ¿Están bien los índices?

Answer (score 1):

`java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` se lanza cuando intenta acceder a una posición en una matriz / vector / cadena que no existe, consulte el código a continuación:

```
    Object[] reservaciones = new Object[5];
    while(RSe.next()){
        reservaciones[0]=RSe.getInt("Id_Reservacion");
        reservaciones[2]=RSe.getString("Fecha_Entrada");
        reservaciones[3]=RSe.getString("Fecha_Salida");
        reservaciones[4]=RSe.getInt("Dias");
        reservaciones[5]=RSe.getString("Id_habitacion");
        DModel.addRow(reservaciones);
    }
```

en tu código creaste un vector de 5 posiciones (0, 1, 2, 3, 4) y estás intentando acceder a la posición número 5, que sería la sexta posición, que no existe.

Simplemente fije las posiciones de los vectores a `[0], [1], [2], [3], [4]` para que se resuelva.